# Получение ID нескольких процессов

Tags: c#

Нужно получить ID определенных процессов.

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("winword, excel, chrome");
List<string> list = new List<string>(); 
list.Add(processes[0].ProcessName.ToString() + " " + processes[0].Id.ToString(););
```

Если указать поиск по одному процессу - все работает, а если указываешь несколько процессов - ошибка. Подскажите, что нужно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с документацией по [`Process.GetProcessesByName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9(v=vs.110).aspx)

Как мы видим, в данном случае вы пытаетесь получить список процессов с названием `winword, excel, chrome` (которого, естественно, нет) и по всей видимости валитесь с `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` при попытке достучаться до первого элемента пустой коллекции. Учтите, что с одним названием может быть несколько процессов (два хрома запущено, например).

Итак, по всей видимости это то, что вам требуется:

```
var processNames = new [] { "winword", "excel", "chrome" };
var list = new List<string>(); 
foreach (var processName in processNames)
{
    var process = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName).FirstOrDefault();
    if (process != null)
    {
        list.Add($"{process.ProcessName} {process.Id}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно. А не подскажете, как исключить добавление одинаковых значений в list? Данное событие стоит в таймере, и получается что каждую секунду он вносит одно и тоже в список

Comment: Очищайте список прежде чем заполнять процессами `list.Clear()`

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли